# Is it possible to run a JPanel (without JFrame) and display all components inside dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So basically, I am trying to get a JPanel window which will display all components inside dynamically. In other words, which will re-size the window, and display to fit its content.

I have been able to do it with help of JFrame and its pack() method which : ["causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29). 
In my situation, I dont want to use JFrame because it will require much effort to make all changes.
Right now, I am able to make it work but only with the help of jscroll inside which wraps the text and or any new lines, so the window size is more static. So my JPanel is extending a TopComponent and am able to display it with:

```
jpanel.open(); 

jpanel.requestActive();
```

So the question is how to resize a window to fit its content upon actions in that window.

Answer (score 2):

The `JPanel` has to be added to a `Window` in order to make sense. So I suggest you use layout managers correctly and you will get to a decent user interface.

Answer (score 2):

When you add/remove components from a visible panel you need to use:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Then the layout manager will lay out the components again.